# Issue with ggplot barchart - labels for included bars only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a bar chart by year. Each year has data for stock market IPOs which are clubbed into 3 categories. I am using the code below to generate the chart

```
graded_graph <-
  ggplot(graded_count, aes(fy, value, fill = parameter, width = 0.75)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') + 
  geom_text(aes(fy, value, label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.75), vjust=-0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual("IPO Market", values = c("blue", "grey", "red"), labels = c("Grade 1 & 2", "Grade 3", "Grade 4 & 5")) +
  ylab("IPOs") + xlab("Fiscal Year") +
  ggtitle("Underpriced IPOs (Based on Issue Grade)")

graded_graph <- graded_graph + theme_tufte() + theme_classic() + theme_phd_min + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"))
```

#### Showing All Columns

[image: Showing All Columns]

I am now excluding bars with a value of 0 by using this code

```
graded_graph <-
  ggplot(graded_count, aes(fy, value, fill = parameter, width = 0.75)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') + geom_text(data=subset(graded_count, value>0),aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual("IPO Market", values = c("blue", "grey", "red"), labels = c("Grade 1 & 2", "Grade 3", "Grade 4 & 5")) +
  ylab("IPOs") + xlab("Fiscal Year") +
  ggtitle("Underpriced IPOs (Based on Issue Grade)")

graded_graph <- graded_graph + theme_tufte() + theme_classic() + theme_phd_min + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"))
```

It now looks like this:

#### Hiding zero value columns

[image: Hiding zero value columns]

How do I get the value labels to be on top of the corresponding columns without it being a little off? This can be seen for the first year and the last year. I have not come across any example where this is solved.

Data snapshot which I am importing from Excel
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtW45.png)

Comment: Replace 0 with empty character values.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? The problem is with how the widths are being calculated internally

Comment: Adding a snapshot of the data which I am importing from Excel.

Comment: @camille I have added the snapshot of the data as a link to the post. Regards.